# Is it safe to add constructor in published structure (used in memcpy)?

Tags: c++, struct

I have a exported structure used in other submodules. Currently it is used to store data. Clients usually copy the object via `memcpy` instead of copy assignment. Now I want to add a constructor on this data-store struct for convenience use.

Is it safe to add member function in exported struct on `memcpy` use? Does the memory layout of the `MyData` object change?

Edited:

The way to use `memcpy` to copy already exist in many modules. I may not able to ask them to replace it. I just concern whether adding this new constructor may break something or not.

```
// MyData.h (Published to other modules)
struct MyData {
    int v1;
    int v2;
    /*
        MyData(): v1(1), v2(2) {}
    */
};

// Other Module's Client.cpp
MyData myData;
memcpy(&myData, &srcData, sizeof myData);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is safe although you will need to recompile all code that uses `MyData`: you can't get away with not doing that.

As for using `memcpy`, you can only do that if the object is *trivially copyable*, else the program behaviour is *undefined*.

If you are in any doubt then you can use `std::is_trivially_copyable<MyData>::value` to check. This will be `true` if, and only if, the object is trivially copyable. You could even wrap that in a `static_assert` to induce a *compile-time* failure. This will guard you from some so-and-so changing your class in such a way that trivial copyability no longer applies (such as someone dogmatically adding a virtual destructor).

The way you currently have it, your `struct` **is** trivially copyable, even *after* you've added the constructor.

Although if I were you I'd just rely on the compiler generated copy constructor and assignment operators.

Comment: I can not ask them to add this check or replace to use copy assignment. So just concern adding this member function may break something or not (without re-compiling).

Comment: You *must* recompile. But `memcpy` will still be safe.

Comment: Is it because adding new ctor may break memory layout or other reason(UB?)?

Comment: +1 for the `trivially_copyable`. most of the developers mistakenly think that only POD types can be copied with `memcpy` where as the standard says otherwise (POD types are subset of trivially copyable types)

Comment: @ChenOT: The facetious answer is that you need to do it because that's the rule. I wouldn't risk it.

Answer (score 2):

Member function does not change memory layouts of the objects. Member functions are just like global functions, but they receives explicit "this" pointer to object from whom they are called. Here is simple example of   memory layout of two objects:

```
struct MyData
{
    int n1;
    int n2;
};

struct MyData_constr
{
    MyData_constr(): n1(1), n2(2) {}
    int n1;
    int n2;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyData data;
    MyData_constr data_constr;

    data.n1 = 1;
    data.n2 = 2;

    printf("MyData size:%d\n", sizeof(MyData));
    printf("MyData_constr size:%d\n", sizeof(MyData_constr));

    printf("\n'data' memory dump:\n");
    unsigned char* pByte = (unsigned char*) &data;
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(MyData); i++)
    {
        printf("%02X ", pByte[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n'data_constr' memory dump:\n");
    pByte = (unsigned char*) &data_constr;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(MyData_constr); i++)
    {
        printf("%02X ", pByte[i]);
    }
    printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
MyData size:8
MyData_constr size:8

'data' memory dump:
01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 

'data_constr' memory dump:
01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 
-------------------------------
```

As you can see the memory layouts and sizes of "data" and "data_constr" are binary equal.

Comment: The addition of a _virtual_ member function can certainly change the size and layout of a struct.

Comment: Yes, it's true.